# Cause of Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "MyUser" does not exist'

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have two databases on the same server, lets call them `DB1` and `DB2`. There is a login on the server called `MyUser`, and both databases have a user setup from that login, also called `MyUser` [edit: and are not orphaned - just double-checked]. The following works fine in `DB2`, but not in `DB1`:

```
execute as user =  'MyUser'
execute as login = 'MyUser'
```

When I run this in `DB1`, I get:

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "MyUser" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

As far as I can tell both `MyUser` users belong to the same roles on their respective databases and those roles have the same permissions that they grant.

To try and figure this out I've run the first `execute as` and then selecting some further information as follows, and this is where it gets interesting:

```
execute as user =  'MyUser'

SELECT *
FROM sys.login_token
WHERE principal_id > 0;

SELECT *
FROM sys.user_token
WHERE principal_id > 0;
```

Now, the output I get for these is as follows. For `DB1` (the problem database) I get (leaving off the `pricipal_id` and `sid` cols), firstly from `sys.login_token`:

| name | type | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyUser | SQL LOGIN | DENY ONLY |
| public | SERVER ROLE | DENY ONLY |

And then from `sys.user_token`, on `DB1`:

| name | type | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyUser | SQL USER | GRANT OR DENY |
| MyRole | ROLE | GRANT OR DENY |

Now, running the same thing in `DB2`, firstly from `sys.login_token`:

| name | type | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyUser | SQL LOGIN | GRANT OR DENY |
| public | SERVER ROLE | GRANT OR DENY |
| sa | SQL LOGIN | AUTHENTICATOR |

And finally from `sys.user_token`, on `DB2`:

| name | type | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyUser | SQL USER | GRANT OR DENY |
| MyRole | ROLE | GRANT OR DENY |
| dbo | SQL USER | AUTHENTICATOR |
| dbo_owner | ROLE | AUTHENTICATOR |

I can't see anything different between the `dbo` database User and `dbo_owner` Role objects between the two databases, nor how the `sa` server login applies at all differently to the two databases, and have no idea how they contribute to these "tokens".

Where should/could I look next to solve this puzzle? (As this is in a highly accessed PROD environment I don't want to make any unnecessary changes)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check if MyUser is orphaned in DB1? 
`USE DB1;
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals a 
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals b ON a.sid = b.sid 
WHERE a.name = 'MyUser' AND b.sid IS NULL);
    PRINT 'MyUser is orphaned.' `

Comment: Double checked. Definitely not orphaned.

Comment: Thank you for checking, from your `user_token` output I see `dbo_owner` role seems to be missing. Can you run these two on `DB1` and see? 
`USE DB1;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyRole';
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'MyRole', 'MyUser';
GO
`

Comment: in `DB2`, `MyRole` is not a member of `db_owner`, and in both `DB1` and `DB2`, `MyUser` is already a member of `MyRole`. I checked with ```SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,   
   isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
 FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
   ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
   ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
ORDER BY DP1.name;  ```

Comment: Seems to me some miss configuration, try with a clean slate and see if that helps.
https://gist.github.com/dvsrk/d5da6da22c7ffdb867a2130f623c1a1f

Comment: You must have an imporsante privilege at the login level to do so... Not only at the database level, or activate the cross db ownerhsip chaining if the user Myuser is the owner of these objetcs.

Comment: Thanks @S.D. but I can't start with a clean slate. These are highly accessed users/logins/tables in prod environment.

Comment: Thanks @SQLpro, I'll have another look at all those privileges - have not found any that are on DB2 that are not on DB1 as yet. They are both on the same server and are using the same logins.